# Scala Splitting with Regex removing the fields instead of splitting

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to parse some logs that look like this:

```
2016-05-16 04:15:16,842 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [pool-3-thread-194]: <PERFLOG method=get_database from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler>
2016-05-16 04:15:16,842 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: [pool-3-thread-194]: 154: get_database: newcluster
```

I am just messing around with how to split this file and every attempt I've made so far like this:

```
val split = hive.map(x=>x.split(":?(\\d{4})")).take(1)
```

Removes the first 4 digits instead of splitting it at the 4 digits?

```
split: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array("", -05-13 00:37:50,808 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [pool-3-thread-194]: </PERFLOG method=drop_table_with_environment_context start=, "", "", 5 end=, "", "", 8 duration=73 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler threadId=154 retryCount=0 error=false>))
```

Why is it removing the field? I have a more complex Regex I've built but just removes everything...

Comment: what do you want to do? Select the date?

Comment: I want to split this up eventually into an Array that is broken into specific elements, one being the time stamp like (\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}), like element 1 is this, element 2 is this..

Comment: Isn't the argument to `split` the *delimiter* on which to split? It seems to be treating `2016` as your delimiter.

Comment: @JeffY exactly, this behaves as expected. The delimiter is not added in the splits, similar to when you split on "," all "," are gone.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apache Spark.

Comment: True, this is a pure scala question.

Comment: @theMadKing: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/jU2qP1/1)?

Answer (score 0):

So make the argument to split instead `"[- :,]"`? What does that give you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create a regex that extract the date pattern:

```
val pattern = """\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}""".r

val log = """2016-05-16 04:15:16,842 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [pool-3-thread-194]: <PERFLOG method=get_database from=org.apache.h"""

pattern.findFirstIn(log)
res: Option[String] = Some(2016-05-16)
```

Following this pattern should help you parse any elements from the log you need.

See [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) for more examples.